# How to import Excel sheet into shiny and update with a button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that allows the user to upload an Excel sheet and then displays it in a datatable it. I then want to perform a function on the table and display the new data.

As far as I understand the process should be 1. Allow the data to be imported with the `fileInput` on the ui.R side

```
sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
        fileInput("csvs",
                  label="Upload CSVs here",
                  multiple = FALSE)
```

**2. Store the data as a reactive value**

```
  data <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$csvs
    if (is.null(inFile)) { return(NULL) }    
    dataFile <- read_excel(inFile$datapath,sheet=1)
    dataFile<-data.frame(EndoPaste(dataFile)[1],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  })

RV <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
```

**3. Show the data in a datatable**

```
  output$endotable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data<-data()
  },options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
```

**4. Allow the user to run a function against the data**

```
  observeEvent(input$textPrep,{

#My custom function
    mywordsOGD<-input$caption
    mywordsOGD<-unlist(strsplit(mywordsOGD,","))
    RV$data<-textPrep(RV$data[,1],mywordsOGD,NegEx="TRUE")

  },ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

**5. Display the new data in the dataTable**

When I run the observe event with browser() RV$data is updated properly, the only issue is that the datatable doesn't show the new values.

I'm sure it is something obvious; how can I display the new values in the datatable?

Comment: "CSVs" and `readxl::read_excel` are not compatible: the former are text files, the latter expects XLS or XLSX files.

Comment: Hi @r2evans that is a naming issue on my part. The excel files actually load up in the datatable fine. They just dont update the way I want

Comment: There are several things about this question that make it incomplete, can you make it more reproducible? For instance, I am *inferring* `readxl` (for `read_excel`) but am not certain about other non-base packages, where does `EndoPaste` come from and what does it do? If you can make this question completely reproducible (make it a full but minimal shiny app), you'll likely get an answer faster.

Comment: @r2evans is right.  I have given an answer but I'm not sure since the question is incomplete. There's high chance my answer will not fit... Provide your functions and the UI (what is `input$textPrep` ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Data1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
Data2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)

observe({
  inFile <- input$csvs
  if (!is.null(inFile)) {   
    dataFile <- read_excel(inFile$datapath, sheet=1)
    dat <- data.frame(EndoPaste(dataFile)[1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    Data1(dat)
    Data2(dat)
  }
})

output$endotable = DT::renderDT({
  Data2()
},options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

observeEvent(input$textPrep,{
  mywordsOGD <- input$caption
  mywordsOGD <- unlist(strsplit(mywordsOGD, ","))
  Data2(textPrep(Data1()[,1], mywordsOGD, NegEx="TRUE"))
},ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the part I didnt understand was that I could use an observe event to simply update the data and then use it separately. Works now